# How to establish trust between two o365 tenants

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

Corporate headquarters has purchased an o365 tenant and configured Exchange, AD, and SharePoint. Location: US Central.

Branch Office has purchased a new o365 tenant and did set up their o365 Exchange online, AD and SharePoint. Location: Oceanic.

Reason to have the separate o365 tenant, they want data to be stored in their own geographical boundary. Don't want to save vendor data/files from Oceanic in Central US.

The client now wants to establish a trust relationship between two tenants. This way the employees will be able to access each other resources ( SharePoint sites etc.,)

**Notes:**

The client doesn't want to give external user access in the tenant to access resources.

Corporate headquarter and branch office are running their respective AD. There is no single AD setup for Corporate and branch office. Currently, there is no AD trust setup.

AD are in sync with Azure AD using directory sync services

Comment: When you say "the client doesn't want to give external user access" are you basically saying that the Azure AD's B2B collaboration feature is not an option? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-collaboration-overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Two O365 tenants are essentially separate companies from the perspective of O365. You can federate Skype for Business and you can share data via SharePoint Online's external sharing capabilities but that's about it. The are some work arounds but no true "trust" like you might be used to with AD.

I would challenge the need for separate tenants. I have never heard of legal requirements for data sovereignty in that region. If there are legal issues that cannot be overcome, we typically recommend an on premises deployment for the branch office and setting  up a hybrid architecture. This will be a much better user experience than separate O365 tenants.